# Magento:: How to filter the excess information?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

i'm trying to get the customer list through an api call & i'm getting the list of customer's details but its returning all the attributes associated with the customers, but i want only **`customer name,employee_id,email`** to be retrieved. in the magento api wiki i found that customer.list accepts two sets of arguments(`array filters & filter list`) could someone tell me the difference b/w the two arguments i tried using the code below to retrive only customer_id,email & firstname but `var_dump();` displays all the customer info how do i retrieve only the attribute's that i want? 
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
     $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.localhost/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('test', '123456');
    // Get new customer info
    $filters=array('employee_id'=>array('eq'=>'234567'));
    $filter_list=array('customer_id','email','firstname');
    $results= $proxy->call($sessionId, 'customer.list',array($filters),array($filter_list));
    var_dump($results);  

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are for retrieving only the customer records that match those specific attributes.

You have several options:

1. Add a new API endpoint to retrieve the values you want.
2. Hack the core Customer wsdl and remove the unwanted attributes.
3. After your API call go through each array and unset the unwanted values.

---

**Adding a custom endpoint**

Well basically you have to create a new module that extends the core api its not hard to do the following guide covers it on detail

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api

Comment: i'm currently using option 3. could you expand a little more on Adding a new end point? i'm trying to retrieve data with least possible overhead & so thought that retrieving only the attributes that i want would decrease this overhead. Thank you!

Comment: Details added, hope it helps if you get stuck let me know. UpVotes are welcome ;)

Comment: after creating the custom api when i make a call to api i'm getting this error, could you please tell me how can i fix this error **SoapFault exception: [102] Customer not exists. in D:\wamp\www\test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 D:\wamp\www\test.php(6): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 D:\wamp\www\test.php(6): SoapClient->call('01f9c6b8498d290...', 'customer.info', Array) #2 {main}**

Comment: i have added the following files in my custom module under /etc 1.api.xml 2.config.xml 3.wsdl.xml & under Model/Objectmodel/api.php & Model/objectmodel/api/v2.php & out from outside of magento i'm making api call from the file test.php, could you please tell me did i missed out any file creation & how can i solve this error, Thanks in advance.